MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in MongoDB Atlas cluster, IP whitelist issue unlikely
I'm encountering an issue while trying to connect my MongoDB Atlas cluster to my Node.js project using Mongoose. Here's a brief breakdown of the problem:
Error:
MongoDB connection error: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist.

.env file:
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://furkanguezel:furkan123@fga-cluster.ffbwprf.mongodb.net/SmartPlan?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=FGA-Cluster

server.js:
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected successfully'))
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err);
    });

Troubleshooting steps taken:
I've added both my current IP and 0.0.0.0 (allowing all IPs) to the IP whitelist in MongoDB Atlas.
The connection string works perfectly in another project with the same configuration.
I've checked the MongoDB network access, and everything seems correct.
Despite the above, I still get the error.
I am currently using a Free-Tier Cluster on MongoDB Atlas, but I also tested with a paid cluster to make sure the issue isn't related to the plan. The problem occurs with both clusters. Additionally, I am using the same cluster in another project, and it works perfectly there.
Node.js Version: v18.15.0
Mongoose Version: mongoose@8.7.2
"dependencies": {
  "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
  "express": "^4.21.1",
  "mongodb": "^6.9.0",
  "mongoose": "^8.7.2"
}

Any suggestions on what else might be causing this issue? Thanks in advance!

I don't believe this was the same issue related to IP whitelisting or network access, as the exact same settings worked perfectly in another project with the same network configuration. I think the problem was specific to the Mongoose version I was using. I hope I'm right about this, but I could be wrong.
Solution:
I managed to solve the issue by downgrading Mongoose from version "^8.7.2" to version "8.4.3":
npm install mongoose@8.4.3
It seems like the latest version of Mongoose caused the connection issue for me. After downgrading, everything worked fine.
I hope this helps others!

If this solved the problem you may write it as an answer. There is nothing wrong if someone answers his own questions.
